# Rails 3: Trouble uploading image files with Carrierwave/Minimagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, minimagick

I've been getting some trouble lately when uploading files with Carrierwave/Minimagick. When I upload an image file (which is to be processed by Minimagick) I get this kind of error:

```
No such file or directory - identify -ping /tmp/mini_magick20130202-16398-ph54gr.jpg
```

This didn't use to happen in my app. Files which are not images give me trouble at all. This is my image uploader file:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  ...

  version :small do
    process :resize_to_fit => [300, 100]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

I found out that not requesting a version of the image, no error happens (but I don't get the version).

Comment: Did you change your storage directory? Check to see if tmp exists. It could be a permission error where `tmp` does not exist and cannot be created by your web-data user.

Comment: tmp directory does exists. I've edited my post to include the image uploader file. When I do not requests versions for an image, no error occurs, and also a new folder is created in the tmp folder (which means there are permissions to write there)

Comment: Have you tried to use minimagick outside of rails and just on commandline. could be an installation issue.

Comment: I had to install Imagemagick to get this working. I thought it was not necessary as I had no trouble installing the gem, but it was